# Cumsum a large ndarray along multiple axes using minimum memory

Tags: python, numpy, cumsum

I have a large ndarray of the lets say shape (a, b, c, d). I wan't to get the cumsum of this array along the 1st and last axes (i.e. a and d). The problem is   loading this array into memory and doing the cumsum takes up a lot of memory. Is there any way I could get the cumsum loading chunks of the whole ndarray at  a time and combining some intermediate results?

Comment: If you don't want to implement it yourself, maybe switching from numpy.ndarray to dask.array is worth a try. Or you can load chunks of the ndarray, compute the cumsum, load the next chunk, combine the cumsums, and so on. But I'd try to avoid doing that by myself.

Comment: Forgetting the size issue for now, do you want `np.cumsum( np.cumsum( arr, axis=1), axis=2)`?

Comment: What's the source of this array?  If the source allows chunked read/write (e.g. memmap `npy` or `h5py`), then processing slices along the first axis shouldn't be too complicated.